# Как автоматически запускать приложение с включением смартфона?

Tags: java, android

Всем доброго дня! У меня возник вопрос: как запускать приложение или выполнять определенный код из него сразу после включения телефона? Тоесть, как только телефон пользователя включается, сразу же запускается наше приложение и выполняет определённый код, возможно без отображения на экране смартфона. Действие, которые в таком режиме приложения выполняет могут быть различны: отправка местоположения на определённый сервер, отправка и получение данных через интернет, считывание данных с устройства и сохранение в своей бд. Буду благодарен за любую информацию, в том числе и ссылкам на другие ресурсы, статьи, книги (в том числе англоязычные).

Comment: а это вообще законно?)

Comment: Конечно, вспомни, что телега, к примеру, постоянно шлет тебе уведомления о том, кто и что тебе написал. Ты же не запускаешь ее каждый раз чтобы узнать пришло ли тебе ченить новое.

Comment: из вашего вопроса можно было понять, то что вы хотите следить за человеком(отправка его местоположения) и сохранять данные взятые с телефона в своей бд. Если вам нужна система уведомлений подправьте свой вопрос.

Comment: Приведенные примеры функционала - это исключительно примеры. Мне нужно лишь знать можно ли это сделать и насколько сложно это сделать. Реализовывать в незаконных целях я это не собираюсь. К примеру, я хочу создать приложение, которое отслеживает местоположение пользователя, и когда он проходит мимо интересного места высылало уведомление об этом, а затем сохраняло это место в своей бд, по запросу пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">  
    <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
    </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

[вот статья](https://habr.com/post/271663/)

а если нужно при разблокировки, то фильтр на выбор

```
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
    <action android:name="android.Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Конечно такое можно сделать. Для этого создаете службу для работы в фоне, в манифесте добавляете соответсвующий `permission`, и регистрируете свой BroadCastReceiver в манифесте, который будет отлавливать старт девайса и выполнять запуск вашей службы, в которой будет лежать нужная вам логика. Подробности можно почитатать, к примеру, [здесь](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-start-android-service-automatically-at-boot-time/).